# Getting value from url for filter field in GridView

Tags: yii2

In my grid view I have added my own filter. But as you can see I had to use "value" to get the value for that input field from url. Other filter fields doesn't require anything, they pick up value automatically, but custom filter field doesn't. I type something in, it accepts and search and after that, field is empty.

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'tableOptions'=>['class'=>'table table-striped table-hover table-bordered responsive',],
        'columns' => [

                [
                        'attribute'=>'date_created',
                        'filter'=>Html::activeTextInput($BreederResultsSearch, 'date_created', ['class'=>'js-datepicker', 'value'=>isset($_GET["BreederResultsSearch"])?$_GET["BreederResultsSearch"]["date_created"]:NULL]),
                ],

                ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
]); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your filter you can add:

```
$this->date_created=Yii::$app->getRequest()->getQueryParam('date_created',NULL);
```

Comment: you mean like this:
'value'=>$this->date_created=Yii::$app->getRequest()->getQueryParam('date_created',NULL)

Comment: Yes, even it is better to put this in your filter, some place such as your model search filter

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could be, that you don't have a public attribute in your SearchModel that gets properly validated by rules. If the attribute is not in the rules (for your given scenario) it doesn't take the value but sets the field/attribute to be null.

This part of the docu explains how filtering with SearchModels and attributes works. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-widgets.html#filtering-data

**Edit:** Also to mention is maybe, that the filters don't get their values from the url, but from the according attributes of the model that is transfered to the view (filterModel of your gridview)

**Edit:**
Is the searchModel the same model you use for the activeInputField in the filter? It should! or did you just rename it here?

Comment: my attribute "date_created" is attribute from database, so everything about this attribute is generated by gii. I just added my own filter

Comment: can you debug that your model attributes are actually loaded and validated and the conditions in the search function are actually met and not an empty dataProvider is returned?

Comment: Search is working just fine, only problem is that it doesn't pick value from URL

Comment: The model for the activeInput should be the filterModel. Is this the breederResultsSearch or did you rename it?